# PhpStorm. Highlight file in project tree on inspection error (e.g. Strict type checking rules violation)

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is it possible to highlight a file in the project tree on inspection error (e.g. Strict type checking rules violation) in PhpStorm?

I would like to highlight it as a serious error. Couldn't find anything in settings and documentation.

[image]

Now it just highlighted the wrong property and mark the line on the right.
v[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that it will work (as it may be limited to certain types only) but try changing the severity for that Inspection to a more serious one. (P.S. I personally do not like an idea of having such an excessive red, especially in the Project View)

Comment: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-inspection-severities.html 2) If you do not know which inspection is that, you can reach it right from the editor (the `Alt+Enter` / light bulb icon Quick Fix menu) -- just expand the submenu (`Arrow Right` key or using a mouse and select the appropriate menu entry "Edit Inspection profile settings"). Check this image for how to access it in general: https://resources.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/2022.3/ws_suppress_inspection_js_class_light.animated.gif

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks to reply. I tried to create custom inspection severity, but there is no any option to mark the file, only code in the editor.

Comment: I am sure that the wrong type will cause an exception, so I think the file should be marked to pay my attention.

Comment: *"so I think the file should be marked to pay my attention. "* This is all persona ofc. But you already have this in the editor itself: the error stripe marks on the scrollbar, the overall marker in the top right corner. You see -- in order for the IDE to mark a file with this info, it needs to actually analyze the file (which it does only with open files or when running Inspect Code on demand)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought it would be possible by changing the Inspection Severity to the highest `Error` level (see the [official doc page on how to configure Inspection Severity](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-inspection-severities.html))... but apparently this will not work.

It seems that right now only certain *hardcoded error types* (that come from lower level Lexer/Parser *as I understand*) can display the "red underwave" in the Project View panel.

Watch the following ticket: <s>[PhpStorm's WI-33552](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-33552)</s> --> [platform-wide IDEA-96288](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-96288) (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress.

It's not the same of course, but will give yo an overview on a most-important errors (for your filtering level/inspection profile).

---

**As a possible alternative:** Run Inspect Code manually (`Code | Inspect Code` from the Main Menu; you can invoke it for a specific folder/custom scope to limit the number of files to be processed) and then filter you results in the *Problems toolwindow* to only see the errors with required severity.

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/running-inspections.html#run-inspections-manually
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/problems-tool-window.html#854a2648